# Why does drag and drop of text from QLineEdit to QPushButton work, but not to QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to learn something from [this PyQt5 example](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/dragdrop/). You can select text of a `QLineEdit`, drag and drop it on a `QPushButton` to rename the button. This works very well.

But I want to use `QTreeWidget` as the drop target as well. Instead of renaming the button, the selected text is supposed to reset the header label. So I adjusted the code to fit `QTreeWidget`. However, it doesn't even show the "drop mouse cursor" when dragging the text over to the `QTreeWidget`.

What's wrong?

This is the full code, which is reduced to the essential: it shows the problem with `QTreeWidget` while working fine with `QPushButton`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidget, QPushButton, QWidget, QLineEdit, QApplication

class Tree(QTreeWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore() 

    def dropEvent(self, e):

        self.setHeaderLabel(e.mimeData().text()) 


class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore() 

    def dropEvent(self, e):

        self.setText(e.mimeData().text()) 


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        edit = QLineEdit('', self)
        edit.setDragEnabled(True)
        edit.move(30, 65)

        tree = Tree(self)
        tree.move(190, 65)

        button = Button("Button", self)
        button.move(30, 120)

        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 400)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Try to call QDragEnterEvent::acceptProposedAction() in dragEnterEvent. You should also reimplement dragMoveEvent() in the same way of dragEnterEvent

Comment: @Fabio Thank you so much! :-) `acceptProposedAction()` wasn't necessary - adding `def dragMoveEvent(self, e)` fixed it already. If you write your comment as an answer, I can mark this issue as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reimplement `dragMoveEvent()` in the same way of `dragEnterEvent()`.
The default implementation could ignore the event, depending on the item under the mouse cursor.

Comment: Thank you :-) Do you mean that the default implementation might ignore the event, because I should use dropping on `QTreeWidgetItem` instead of `QTreeWidget` itself? Because I had planned that at first - however, `QTreeWidgetItem` doesn't seem to have any of the pre-written events like `dragEnterEvent()`. That's where I failed initially.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the implementation of QTreeWidget can manage only drag & drop of QTreeWidgetItems, depending on the item flags and on the DragDropMode of the widget. If you want to manage you custom d&d you should reimplement the QTreeWidget as you have done.